# Does resource id changes everytime an application starts

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am storing my images in drawable and their resource id in SQLite database.My database is created when the application starts for the first time.

Is it good to save the image ids in database or does the id's change every time an application start?

if id's change then while fetching back image id's I may receive an error.So,is storing image ID in database a good idea?

i need the images path to be stored in database with other relative data that's why i am storing the image id's in data base.

Comment: I don't think it will change each time it starts.the ids should be generated when you compile your code.

Comment: And no, storing image ids in the db is a bad idea, because they won't be valid if you push an update.

Comment: @GabeSechan-thnx for suggession i'll find an alternate solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the best way was to store image name directly into database and fetch it,then use

```
int resID = this.getResources().getIdentifier("your photo name fetched from database","drawable","package name");

image.setResourceID(resID);
```

Answer (score 5):

One approach would be storing the drawables in strings.xml as a string array something like this:

```
 <string-array name="location_flags">
    <item>@drawable/ic_image_name</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_image_name</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_image_name</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_image_name</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_image_name</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_image_name</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_image_name</item>
</string-array>
```

Then reading this array in your activity code :

```
TypedArray locationFlags=getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.location_flags);
```

Then applying the for loop you can get the Drawable something like this:

```
for(int i=0i<locationFlags.length();i++)
 {

   Drawable drawable = locationFlags.getResourceId(i, -1);
 }
```

Be sure to recycle the TypedArray after using it, since its a shared resource :

```
 locationFlags.recycle();
```

Comment: not sure whether it would work as the images are linked to some data in database and i want to fetch it along the data.There are a lot of images,So i doubt whether the above method will work or not.

Comment: You didn't mention any relationship between the data and images so I suggest the said solution.

Comment: getResourceId(i, -1) should be Int and not Drawable

Answer (score 0):

It is Bad idea to store ids, But what is your purpose??
better idea is to store thumbnails to database rather than ids..
this helped me
[may this example help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930681/how-to-store-thumbnails-for-easy-retrieval)
do following steps

1. get thumbnails of your image

   final int thumbnailSize = 128;// define your size

   Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath), 
                   THUMBSIZE, THUMBSIZE);
2. Convert it into Byte array

   Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.thumbnail);
   ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
   byte[] buffer=out.toByteArray();
3. Save it as Blob

   ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(CHUNK, buffer);       //CHUNK blob type field of your table
    long rawId=database.insert(TABLE, null, cv); //TABLE table name

   I havnt used this but this may help you

Comment: do you mean storing the images as BLOB files in database?

Comment: well the images are quite heavy and are also quite more in numbers so storing as blob is not an option