# Insert Integer Value in Sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, int

I m trying to insert Integer value but its can't accept the values.its take second String value and give Exception of datatype

this is my inserting code

```
void addCategory(Category Category) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_IMG, Category.getimg()); // Category Name
    values.put(KEY_NAME, Category.getName()); // Category Name
    values.put(KEY_SELECTION, Category.isSelected()); // Category Phone

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CategoryS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

This is Selection Code

```
public List<Category> getAllCategorys() {
    List<Category> CategoryList = new ArrayList<Category>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CategoryS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        do {
            Category Category = new Category();
            Category.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            Category.setimg(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
            Category.setName(cursor.getString(2));
            Category.setSelected(cursor.getString(3));
            CategoryList.add(Category);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return Category list
    return CategoryList;
}
```

this is Values

```
db.addCategory(new Category(R.drawable.angle, "Angle", "true"));
db.addCategory(new Category(R.drawable.angle, "Area", "true"));
db.addCategory(new Category(R.drawable.angle,"Currency", "true"));
db.addCategory(new Category(R.drawable.angle,"Current", "true"));
db.addCategory(new Category(R.drawable.angle,"Density", "true"));
db.addCategory(new Category(R.drawable.angle,"Length", "true"));
```

This is Logcat error:

```
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "Angle"
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
```

its can't take int value . its move up to "Angle" value

this is my create table query

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CategoryS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CategoryS + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_IMG + "INTEGER," +
        KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_SELECTION + " TEXT"  + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CategoryS_TABLE);
}
```

This is my Category Class:

```
public class Category 
{
    int id;
    int img;
    String name = null;
    String selected = "true";
    public Category()
    {

    }

    public Category(int img, String name, String selected) {

        this.name = name;
        this.selected = selected;
        this.img = img;
    }
    public Category(int id,int img, String name, String selected) {

        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.selected = selected;
        this.img = img;
    }

    public int getID() { return id; }

    public void setID(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getimg() { return img; }

    public void setimg(int img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(String selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show create table SQL Query

Comment: Category.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0))); why are you parsing  "Angle" to int

Comment: You show table SQLite structure and Category class

Comment: no i m not parse "angle" into int. instead of "R.drawable.angle" its take "Angle" Value and Give error

Comment: @Aanal Shah: How many columns are der in Database Table?

Comment: there  are 4 columns id int,img int, name text,selected text

Comment: it's a bad idea to store resource-id in the sqlite db. If you compile the next time, the resource-id changes... while your db still pointing to the old id. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837083/does-resource-id-changes-everytime-an-application-starts

Comment: then what should do to refere resoruce in db

Comment: @AanalShah: try to uninstall app then run it because probably you have changed create table query after db is created

Comment: thanks you its Work @ ρяσѕρєя K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change below lines in code -

```
Category.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
Category.setimg(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
```

To -

```
Category.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
Category.setimg(cursor.getInt(1));
```

change your create table query as below -

```
String CREATE_CategoryS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CategoryS + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_IMG + " INTEGER," +
        KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_SELECTION + " TEXT"  + ")";
```

Comment: its can't insert  and give error  `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 3 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.`

Comment: alright u r not inserting ID value in table so either u enter it manually or just Auto increment will do

Comment: its auto increment when i remove img column id generate automatically

Comment: just change the create table query and see if it works

Comment: i change the query ` "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CategoryS + "("
    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_IMG + "INTEGER," +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_SELECTION + " TEXT"  + ")";` but its give same error

Comment: I guess the problem is while retrieving and not while insertion.

Comment: its not insert 3rd row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103568/discussion-between-kevz-and-aanal-shah).

Comment: der shd be space KEY_IMG + " INTEGER,"

Answer (score 0):

if you modify the table of your db you have to change the version of the db or you can uninstall and reinstall the app.While reading from cursor,always use `cursor.movetoFirst` before traversing the cursor.