# Does the ID of a drawable changes in Android?

Tags: android, android-drawable

For example I have an image `background1.jpg` and I this is the code to get the ID

```
int background = R.drawable.background1;
```

I then uploaded `int background` to the database. I closed the app and open it again then I retrieved the ID from the database that was saved earlier and set it in an ImageView

```
int background = json.getInt("background");
image.setImageResource(background);
```

Is it possible to do this? Does the `R.drawable.background1` changes from time to time? Because I was wondering why the background didn't change the second time I run my app.

Comment: it remains the same. and why have u added json.getINT FOR BACKGROUND

Comment: what is the log of background. can u try that

Comment: do a log.d for background int variable

Comment: @Athul so maybe I got something wrong in my code. Sorry, it's just a sample.  That isn't the actual code.

Comment: can u post it. SO that ican check

Comment: Here is the answer to your question. 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837083/does-resource-id-changes-everytime-an-application-starts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can get the int id from String

**Try This**

```
int background = getResources().getIdentifier("background", "drawable", "com.example.package");

image.setImageResource(background);
```

Comment: I see. So getting the R.drawable.background1 is different from this?